# What happens when in offline sorting the dataset size exceeds RAM size?

Tags: sorting

What happens when in offline sorting the dataset size exceeds RAM size?
I have to sort a large text file and want to know what happens if the size of my text file file exceeds the RAM size.

Comment: Just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Offline sorting is precisely designed to work in the case where you can't fit your data set into RAM. The general idea is to split the data set apart into smaller pieces, each of which *can* fit into memory, and to sort each piece independently of the others. Afterwards, you can combine them all together.

The most common external sorting algorithm is an external mergesort. You begin by splitting your input apart into blocks of some fixed size - usually, as much as you can fit into RAM at one time - then sort those blocks independently and write the sorted versions back to disk. You then do a k-way merge operation to combine all of the sorted sequences back together; the specific algorithm used is usually a generalization of the normal 2-way merge algorithm combined with some buffering to minimize disk reads.

A less common approach is to use quicksort and a double-ended priority queue. You can read more about this [here](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c13/double.htm).